# Confusion between work account & Microsoft account

Tags: azure, microsoft-account

I am using my work email address to set up multiple Azure IaaS environments. When I log into Azure, I get asked if I want to use the "Work or School Account" or "Personal Account" - both referring to the same email address.

I don't recall setting up anything in terms of personal accounts, or linking my work email as a Microsoft Outlook.com/Hotmail/etc account.

Access to the subscription has been applied to my Personal account, not the work one.

When granting access, there's no way to pick which one you're giving access to.

Couple of questions

1. I've created some VMs but want them to be linked to my work account. Can I change this?
2. How do I unlink my work email from Personal. I want to use work just for work, and not have any confusion between the two.

See this screengrab for more information:

[image: screengrab of issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few problem with your account so lets go over them one by one.

First means that now you have 2 different accounts one it is your work account another one it is your microsoft account. You can create both of them with the same email since they are from 2 different tenants.

This is a concept important or you to understand there is something on Azure that it is over the subscription that is the tenant

```
Tenant
 |- Subscription
    |- Resource Group
       |- Resource
```

All subscription under the same tenant have the same Authentication method, this Authentication method can be linked to an Azure Active Directory ( Office 365 subscriptions are Azure Active Directory ) So you can open a request to microsoft to transfer your subscription to your company tenant. if you do this all the resources under it will be transferred to your other authentication. You can open this ticket on the [portal](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade).

If you don't want your personal account anymore you can close it on https://account.live.com/closeaccount.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who edited the question for me, my line-breaks didn't work by default, I'll ensure that I get it write next time. I was only allowed to post the image as an attachment being first-time poster, someone fixed that for me.

The answer from Gabriel Monteiro Nepomuceno was correct and touched on the root cause, but there's one element I didn't include in my question.

Regarding the tenant: the tenant is created under the company account of "company.com". I am a sub-contractor and was granted access to my own account at "benscompany.com". Azure support have advised that its only possible to grant access to different account via the personal account.